# C++ string initialization with copies of character?

Tags: c++, string

I'm studying C++.
My textbook is, starting out with C++ from control structures through objects 7th.
In the string class explanation, there is a code

```
string lineFull('z', 20); 
// Defines a string object named lineFill initialized with 10 'z' characters
```

I tried this code on my computer, but doesn't work. Is this code right? or any dependency/requirement for this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please do not ever say "doesn't work". Tell us the full error message, copied verbatim.

Comment: alright! Thanks for your great advice. I need to be more specific in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the correct syntax is

```
string lineFull(20, 'z')
```

from the [`std::string` constructor docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for this constructor is:

```
std::string::string(size_t n, char c);
```

so you need:

```
string lineFull(20, 'z');
```